# PHP acessing array contained in SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml

The code bellow

```
<?php 

$ans=<<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResponseDoc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <response>
    <index>1</index>
    <statusCode>Success</statusCode>
  </response>
  <response>
    <index>2</index>
    <statusCode>Success</statusCode>
  </response>
  <response>
    <index>3</index>
    <statusCode>Success</statusCode>
  </response>
  <response>
    <index>4</index>
    <statusCode>Success</statusCode>
  </response>
</ResponseDoc>
XML;

$r1= simplexml_load_string($ans);
        print_r($r1);
echo '<br>---------------------------------<br>';       
        $r2=$r1->response;  
        print_r($r2);
echo '<br>---------------------------------<br>';       

?>
```

gives the bellow output

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
  [response] => 
  Array ( 
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [index] => 1  [statusCode] => Success ) 
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [index] => 2  [statusCode] => Success ) 
    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [index] => 3  [statusCode] => Success ) 
    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [index] => 4  [statusCode] => Success )
  ) 
)

---------------------------------
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [index] => 1 [statusCode] => Success )
---------------------------------
```

I cannot understand why, as in my current mental model the $r2 should contain an array instead of the value of the array at index 0.
If I loop

```
foreach($r1 as $i) echo "statusCode='{$i->statusCode}'<br>";        
foreach($r1->response as $i) echo "statusCode='{$i->statusCode}'<br>";
```

the output in both cases (and I don't understand why it works in the first case) is:

```
statusCode='Success'
statusCode='Success'
statusCode='Success'
statusCode='Success'
```

probably I am missing some difference between objects and arrays or there is some special detail regarding SimpleXMLElement or print_r and var_dump work incorrectly.

Comment: The SimpleXML extension uses a lot of "magic". A `SimpleXMLElement` object is not a regular object; what `print_r()` shows is not the real content. There are no arrays here, just objects that look like arrays.

Comment: Up to there I had arrived, what I don't understand is next steps.

Comment: I believe that `$r2=$r1->response` is actually a shorthand for `$r2=$r1->response[0]`. Remember, this is the “simple” parser, and I think this shortcut is meant for something like this: https://3v4l.org/QouOD. Without some of the magic you’d have to write https://3v4l.org/pURrs

Comment: @ChrisHaas They don't mean the same thing. `$r1->response` is an iterator over the `response` children elements. `$r1->response[0]` represents only the first `response` element.

Comment: @ChrisHaas But if you call `__toString()` on an iterator object, it will forward the call to the first element indeed. So `echo $r1->Name` is equivalent to `echo $r1->Name->__toString()` which is equivalent to `echo $r1->Name[0]->__toString()`.

Comment: @Olivier, I stand corrected!

Comment: Starts to make some sense ... but more semantics should be added over the whole simpleXmlElement workings.

Answer (score 0):

The output is correct, because the simple xml parser gives you the first object automatically. But you can overcome this by using the xpath method. You also can use the `print_r($responses)` to view the array of each item beeing a SimpleXMLElement.

You also can directly use foreach, because the SimpleXml parser checks for array context.

```
foreach($r1->reponse as $item)
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/BXhC2
Demo: https://3v4l.org/5bJNZ (with print_r())

```
$r1        = simplexml_load_string($ans);
$responses = $r1->xpath('//response');

foreach ($responses as $item) {
    echo $item->index, PHP_EOL;
    echo $item->statusCode, PHP_EOL;
}

print_r($responses);
```

```
1
Success
2
Success
3
Success
4
Success
```

And the output with `print_r($responses)`

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [index] => 1
            [statusCode] => Success
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [index] => 2
            [statusCode] => Success
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [index] => 3
            [statusCode] => Success
        )

    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [index] => 4
            [statusCode] => Success
        )
)
```

Comment: *"you can overcome this by using the xpath method"* There is absolutely no need to use XPath. `foreach($r1->response as $item)` does iterate over all `response` elements.

Comment: @Olivier But in the question you can NOT use print_r($r1->response) to see the full array. That makes the difference. I've updated the answer to hopefully make it clearly understandable.

Comment: So you mean that $r1->xpath('//response') gives the array ?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis Yes, it does. See the answer with output and demo updated.